# Centre an image in two-column article while using multicols and figure*

Tags: floats, two-column, multicol

I have 5 images in a two-column article which as of now using `multicols` and `figure*` appear like this.

```
\begin{figure*} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{0.001.eps}\par 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{0.005.eps}\par 
    \end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{0.010.eps}\par
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{0.030.eps}\par
\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{0.050.eps}\par 
\end{multicols}
\caption{Here is the caption}
\label{here is the label}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

**However I would like to center the last image. How do I achieve it?**

Comment: What about replacing the last `\begin{multicols}{2}` by `\begin{multicols}{2}\centering` and maybe removing the `\par` in the next line? And - doesn't `figure*` leave already? IMHO you may not neet the `multicols` parts but can just use `hspace` (or `subfigure`s)

Comment: @Ronny: Your first solution doesn't seem to work, that was the first thing I tried before. Can you explain in more detail about the use of hspace to achieve this?

Comment: I wrote an answer - though that does not use `multicols` as requested. The second solution uses `subcaption`, because I like to write code, that describes _what_ there is, here: subfigures :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it using the tabular environment!

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{0.001.eps} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{0.005.eps}   \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{0.010.eps} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{0.030.eps}   \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{0.050.eps}}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Here is the caption}
\end{figure*}
```

Here by using `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]` the last figure get's centered!

Answer (score 4):

The lazy way could be to use just hspaces; something like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\hspace{.005\linewidth} 
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\\[.5\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\hspace{.005\linewidth} 
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\\[.5\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{5 Images.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

which yields something like
[image: hspace approach]

Note that here, the linebreaks are extended by half a baseline to introduce space between the images.

I would favour, however, a solution with `subcaption` which also allows for referencing subfigures (i.e. Fig. 1(a) and such) using

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{First.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Second.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Third.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Fourth.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Fifth.}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{5 Images.}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Which yields
[image: Subcaption approach]
Note that this needs relative sizes internally, i.e. `\linewidth` in the subfigure refers to the width of the subfigure itself. This can further be styled by using the options from subcaption (sublabel style spacing and so on). And maybe you want to use `\centering` also inside the subfigures - I'll leave the code as it is, because it directly generates the corresponding image.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used for subfigure with three plots

`\begin{figure*} \centering     %%% not \center \subfigure[Figure A]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{images/congestion_less.pdf}} \subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{images/congestion_medium.pdf}} \par\medskip \subfigure[Figure B]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{images/congestion_high.pdf}} \caption{my caption} \end{figure*}`[image]

Comment: Welcome on this site. Would you mind providing a compilable code with `\documentclass`, minimum required `pakages`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` ?